# Apache(2.2.22) not starting after enabling SSL on windows7

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

Installed Apache on win 7 and previously(without enabling SSL) its worked successfully. After Configuring SSL on httpd.conf,while trying to restart through monitor(stop then start) its prompting below error. please help me otu of this issue.

```
  The Request Operation has failed
```

while trying start apache through services getting below error

```
"Windows couldn't start Apache 2.2 on local PC. For more information check system events log. If it's not a windows service contact service provider and reference the code:1"
```

Apache Verion is

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin>httpd.exe -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32)
Server built:   Jan 28 2012 11:16:39
```

while executing httpd.exe -e debug,

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin>httpd.exe -e debug
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module actions_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module alias_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module asis_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module auth_basic_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_default_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_file_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_default_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_groupfile_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_host_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_user_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module autoindex_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module cgi_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module dir_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module env_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module imagemap_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module include_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module isapi_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module log_config_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module mime_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module negotiation_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module setenvif_module
[Fri Jan 15 15:06:51 2016] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module userdir_module
```

in httpd.con file,updated the below entries

```
Listen <ipadress>:81
ServerAdmin admin@www.d235y.com => www.d235y.com->domain name created after executing "openssl" command=> openssl req -new -out server.csr
    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

in httpd-ssl.conf file,

```
Listen 10.94.2.44:8443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
ServerName www.d235y.com:443
ServerAlias d235y.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@www.d235y.com
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/access.log"
```

certificates file entries are as follows

```
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/server.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/server.key"
```

Comment: **For more information check system events log**. Did you?

Comment: @ Álvaro González,  in Event properties, its showing like this
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Apache Service
Date:          1/15/2016 3:41:49 PM
Event ID:      3299
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:    d235y.asia.group.com
Description:
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> SSLSessionCache: Invalid argument: size has to be >= 8192 bytes